# HashMap inside HashMap vs Map.Entry inside HashMap Java

Tags: java, hashmap

Soo, i need to store a nonce, a user and the user's IP
I thought of puting a HashMap inside a HashMap like the following:
`private Map<BigInteger, HashMap<User, String>> users;`

But found that someone instead of doing what I thought of doing, did this:

`private Map<BigInteger, Map.Entry<User, String>> users;`

(Variable types differ)

But I wanted to know, what would be better and if there's a better way of doing what I'm trying to do. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: what about using a compound key instead of nested maps? Like `Map<Pair<BigInteger, User>, String>`.

Comment: Not to (necessarily) recommend a specific product or package, but have you heard of [redis](https://redis.io/)?

Comment: They're not equivalent. The inner hash map is a collection. A Map.Entry is only a pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a class to keep `User` and `IP` together.

```
@Getter @AllArgsConstructor
public class SessionInfo {
    private User user;
    private String IP;
}
```

and use a map utilizing this class:

```
Map<BigInteger, SessionInfo> users;
```

---

Note: In the question's example, Map.Entry is used as a class holding two values. A dedicated class is better.

Note-2: Map in Map is not a good idea for this case. As long as you do not want to have more than one user per nonce, do not use Map in Map.